# Open a new Stage with Jmenuitem

Tags: javafx

hey folks as you see in the code I want to add new  stage in the jmenuitem
but it give me this error because I cant use swing with stage as I think
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNGPf.png)

and here is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDXnX.png)

Comment: Don't post code as images, post code as text formatted as code (same for stack traces and error messages).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing Swing and JavaFX is not recommended unless you really know what you are doing and have a really good reason for it.

Otherwise, don't import swing and awt classes into a JavaFX project, only import JavaFX classes.

[JavaFX has menu system support](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/menu_controls.htm). If you are using JavaFX then use that.

You appear to want a [ContextMenu](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html) rather than an application menu.  JavaFX supports both types and both are documented in the referenced tutorial.

Comment: i will try that , thanks for help